# Why is the variance of my model predictions much smaller than the training data?

Tags: keras, variance, gru

I trained a GRU model on some data and then created a bunch of predictions on a test set.

The predictions are really bad, as indicated by a near zero R2 score.

I notice that the variance of the model predictions are much smaller than the actual training data. i.e it seems like the model is overfit to the mean:

[image]

But why is this? I made sure to stop training/use hyperparameters where there was no model overfitting, so why are model predictions centred around the mean and less dispersed than the actual variance of the data set?

My model, if it is relevant:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 280), recurrent_dropout = 0.2, dropout = 0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.summary()

# fit model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=40, verbose=1, validation_split=0.33)
```

Comment: What about the features in your model should make something jump out as being far from the mean?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do here is to scale your output data before training the model. For instance

$$
\dfrac{x_i - \bar{x}_{train}}{\sigma_{x_{train}}}
$$

If that does not work, then you can have a look at the model and / or training parameters.

Comment: Yes, I normalised the variables before training.

Comment: then something is off, if you used some sort of scaling before training the variance should be lower. What scaling did you use?

Comment: The variance *is* lower. I used the same equation you presented to normalise the variables.

Comment: So, it just occurred to me that I need to un-normalise the predictions right?

Comment: yes - in order to avoid bias you need to estimate the normalisation parameters on the training set (save them somewhere) then you can use these values to un-normalise the prediction